# How can I parse this specific XML data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to parse this XML, and I can't extract all of the "

" texts in that file, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the HTTP /GET that I'm trying to make a request to,

**request_link**:"https://cdnsecakmi.kaltura.com/api_v3/index.php/service/caption_captionAsset/action/serve/captionAssetId/0_o7nr2wfk/v/2/ks/djJ8MjAxMTUzMXyLXeiobMjq3pQ7i9wYSlwZHhVUdAP8C6IYMqJGpcDqOsBc4X5e0rTARtFc6ysPSkDTq_u7qfycIGeJquoL_O_3MlBxOn9rBGgQBZXeeAQrcd8tmZqjZo2h5bQVGtQXgFHVc7OyICn-cY2lHa4ZjRp6w2ueyIRqyNp9pHZ5onX2Z6gfjyNR4MubV3V6Qwfa3e0hbRdAoCap1dgO2QIawMKi/.dfxp"

```
const get_religion_notes = new XMLHttpRequest();
get_religion_notes.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       console.log(get_religion_notes.responseXML)
       
       let parser = new DOMParser();
       xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(get_religion_notes,"text/xml");
       console.log(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[0])
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; //Undefined why is that?
    }
};
get_religion_notes.open("GET", "https://cdnsecakmi.kaltura.com/api_v3/index.php/service/caption_captionAsset/action/serve/captionAssetId/0_o7nr2wfk/v/2/ks/djJ8MjAxMTUzMXyLXeiobMjq3pQ7i9wYSlwZHhVUdAP8C6IYMqJGpcDqOsBc4X5e0rTARtFc6ysPSkDTq_u7qfycIGeJquoL_O_3MlBxOn9rBGgQBZXeeAQrcd8tmZqjZo2h5bQVGtQXgFHVc7OyICn-cY2lHa4ZjRp6w2ueyIRqyNp9pHZ5onX2Z6gfjyNR4MubV3V6Qwfa3e0hbRdAoCap1dgO2QIawMKi/.dfxp", true);
get_religion_notes.send();
```

Comment: Rare that api's serving xml are CORS enabled and this one is not. You need to use a proxy either on your server or third party service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything is correct.

just make sure your using `responseText` parser requires text xml not xml itself..

```js
const get_religion_notes = new XMLHttpRequest();
get_religion_notes.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       console.log(get_religion_notes.responseText)
       
       let parser = new DOMParser();
       xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(get_religion_notes.responseText,"text/xml");
       console.log(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[0])
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; //Undefined why is that?
    }
};
get_religion_notes.open("GET", "https://cdnsecakmi.kaltura.com/api_v3/index.php/service/caption_captionAsset/action/serve/captionAssetId/0_o7nr2wfk/v/2/ks/djJ8MjAxMTUzMXyLXeiobMjq3pQ7i9wYSlwZHhVUdAP8C6IYMqJGpcDqOsBc4X5e0rTARtFc6ysPSkDTq_u7qfycIGeJquoL_O_3MlBxOn9rBGgQBZXeeAQrcd8tmZqjZo2h5bQVGtQXgFHVc7OyICn-cY2lHa4ZjRp6w2ueyIRqyNp9pHZ5onX2Z6gfjyNR4MubV3V6Qwfa3e0hbRdAoCap1dgO2QIawMKi/.dfxp", true);
get_religion_notes.send();
```

Comment: wait a second, i'll revert you.

Comment: neh dude.. i checked and it is running fine

Comment: @ChrisWang please test

Comment: but that gets only 1 "<p>" I want all of the "<p>"'s

Comment: @ChrisWang you can remove [0] that means only first p. let me know your findings

Comment: Actually why is it parsing "<br .............>" then it has some like weird links to http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml. I want just the text within the "<P>" how do I do that?

Comment: @ChrisWang wait incase you want only text

Comment: nvm I figured it out,

Comment: well u can use 
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
 temp1[i].innerText;
}